# Permissions on folder, retain after being set?

Tags: unix

I have a folder, I've changed permissions to 777. Later a script uploads to this folder, and what is put inside does not have the same permissions as the parent folder.

Is there a way to specify on the parent folder that all sub folders should have open permissions? And for this to take effect on folders and files uploaded into the folder after permissions have been set?

Please note, I have no way to change the uploading script - but i do know the script does not explicitly set permissions for its uploads.

Comment: Do you really need 777 permission? An access control list [setfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) may be a better option there. Or assign the folder owner to the same group(s) as the upload script(s).

Comment: is this working sudo chmod 777 -R folder

Comment: owaishanif786 this does not work.

Comment: Evert - yes I need 777

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory